# Calculating the APR

Tags: c#

I'm using the Microsoft.VisualBasic Assembly to use [`rate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.rate?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Pmt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.pmt?view=netframework-4.7.2) for some reason when i run my code it keeps giving me a completely wrong number

I've thoroughly read the docs and cant seem to identify the issue:

```
origFee30YearRate = 0.04875M;
double Nper = 360;
double Pmt = Financial.Pmt((double)(origFee30YearRate / 12), Nper, 100000);
double PV = ((Pmt * Nper) * -1) - 1775.25;

var org30APR = (Financial.Rate(Nper, Pmt, PV)) * 12;
```

The values come out to be:

```
Nper: 360
Pmt: -529.20822384932933
PV: 188739.71058575856
```

I'm not sure whats going wrong here with calculating the `Rate`
The output from `Rate` is: `0.0006268633835987544` where is should be `5.14`

Comment: you should change the magic numbers in your `PV` assignment statement to `double`s (i.e. `15`->`15d`), especially the ones that are being used for division.  e.g. the `(1/100)` part will always result in the RHS of the first `-` being `-1775.25`.

Comment: @Charles - FWIW...I worked for a bank a year ago and had to build a loan proposal app which required APR to be calculated on the fly based changes to the loan...ie...amount, interest rate, term, etc.   I spent over a month working to get it right with multiple loan officers checking my work along the way.  The only way to accurately do what you are after is to calculate the amortization schedule for the life of the loan and use the remaining balance to identify the APR over the term.   Financial.Rate looks promising, but will not get you what you need.   The code to get it right is a beast.

Comment: @user1011627 any way you have that code?

Comment: What is PV, what are you trying to calculate? 360 payments @ $529.21 is $190,515.16, your calculated PV is $188,789.71. Does that sound like 5.14% to you? Fix your PV and your call to `Financial.Rate` should fix itself.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller PV is the value of the loan, i guess i cant seem to figure out PV correctly from my understanding its the life of the loan(360) * the monthly payment(529.21) subtracting the lending fees. Not sure why this isn't adding up

Comment: Sorry, I don't.

Comment: @Charles `PV` is the amount borrowed, not the amount paid. Pretty sure you simply need to subtract the lending fees from 100000 given your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start your `origFee30YearRate` appears to be incorrect. 4.75% should be assigned as 0.0475 not 4.75. Also, you appear to be incorrectly changing the sign of the payment.

```
double origFee30YearRate = 0.0475;

double Nper = 360;
double Pmt = Financial.Pmt(origFee30YearRate / 12, Nper, 100000);
double PV = (100000 - (100000 * origFee30YearRate / 365 * 15) - (100000 * (1 / 100)) - 1775.25);

var org30APR = Financial.Rate(Nper, Pmt, PV) * 12;
```

This returns an interest rate of 4.92%, presumably you're trying to calculate back to 4.75%?

The reason you don't get 4.75% is because `PVal` is how much you borrowed and I'm not entirely sure why you're calculating it.

```
double origFee30YearRate = 0.0475;

double Nper = 360;
double Pmt = Financial.Pmt(origFee30YearRate / 12, Nper, 100000);

var org30APR = Financial.Rate(Nper, Pmt, 100000) * 12;
```

Also, if you want to change your units back to %, simply multiply by 100.

```
var org30APR = (Financial.Rate(Nper, Pmt, 100000) * 12) * 100;
```

For APR, I believe you just need to subtract the fees.

```
var apr = (Financial.Rate(Nper, Pmt, (100000 - 1775.25)) * 12) * 100;
```

Comment: please refer to my comment on OP's post.  `PV` will have the wrong value if you do integer division.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller with a interest rate of 4.75% should return an APR of 5.04%. This algorithm is returning 4.75%